# \Trace/BPT trap: 5 when using open from terminal

Tags: terminal, macos, bash

After upgrading to Maverick, I can't use the open command anymore from the terminal. Whenever I do, I get:

```
$ open http://google.de
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

This is independent on the document chosen.

```
$ open -a Safari
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I use homebrew as well, if this helps.

My .profile is as follow:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
# Finished homebrew

# export PATH=~/bin:xs$PATH

export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

and my .bash_profile is

```
alias emacs="/usr/local/Cellar/emacs/24.3/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -nw"

export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/texbin:$PATH

## Homebrew
export HOMEBREW_GITHUB_API_TOKEN=6fb92887ac7d8317656501ec1193e05e0f360d01
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
source `brew --repository`/Library/Contributions/brew_bash_completion.sh

##
# Your previous /Users/rainerkrug/.bash_profile file was backed up as /Users/rainerkrug/.bash_profile.macports-saved_2013-09-06_at_11:34:21
##


# Finally add ~/bin at first location in PATH
export PATH=~/bin:$PATH

# define EDITOR
export EDITOR="emacs -Q"

# define infopath to get correct info manual of org-mode
# export INFOPATH=$HOME/.emacs.d/org-mode/doc:$HOME/.emacs.d/ess/doc:$INFOPATH/
```

The open command is the correct one:

```
$ which open
/usr/bin/open
```

Any suggestions?

Rainer

Comment: Seemed to be working after a restart, but after starting emacs (installed via homebrew) not working anymore.

Comment: Do you have some interesting messages in the Console app ?

Comment: Does the `open` command work with any applications *other* than Safari (or URLs)? For example: try to use `open` to launch TextEdit: `open -a TextEdit`.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler No - just the one I gave you.

Comment: @EddieKelley Nope - did not work with any app. Nothing. It recognized if the app existed (so giving me the " app not found" message when the app did not exist), but the same error messages with all apps and types I tested.

Comment: OK - it is working again. It must have had something to do with emacs from homwbrew, because I removed homebrew completely, installed the emacs from emacsformac, installed homebrew again and added offlineimap and dovecot which I use to read emails in gnus, and so far it worked perfectly. No explanation why, but the problem is avoided, although not solved.

Comment: could you do a tail -f /var/log/system.log while doing your open, and in another window do an opensnoop while root.

Comment: It is working now - see my previous post. Can I mark the question as solved?

Answer (score 2):

there.  I had this problem and so I cleared out some old launchd plists, some of which dated back to Leopard (I restore via Time Machine when I get a new Mac.)  So far, that seems to have worked.  If you check out "man launchd" and scroll to the bottom, there's a list of folders where such files may be found.  Leave anything by Apple, and clear out the questionable ones.  I no longer have any Adobe software on my Mac, ditto for MS Office, and I'm trying ClamAV instead of Avast, so I cleared out all the Adobe, Microsoft, and Avast plists.  Haven't even rebooted yet and suddenly I can use "open" reliably again.